# Is NASM 'times' directive taken into account when calculating sizes?

Tags: assembly, struct, size, nasm

If I have this structure/section:

```
MyStruct:
    .Data1 dw 2
    .Dats2 dw 3
    times 1000 dw 1
MyStructEnd:

StructSize equ MyStructEnd - MyStruct
```

Will NASM be clever enough to include in the size of MyStruct the bytes declared in the last instruction or just the first two ones?

Comment: Wouldn't that be real easy to test?

Comment: Just [produce a listing file](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html) and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies. Before Nasm knows `MyStruct_size`, you hafta do:

```nasm
; this is just a "typedef"
struc MyStruct
    Data1 resw 1
    Data2 resw 1
    padding times 1000 resw 1
endstruc

section .data
; here, we initialize it
istruc MyStruct
    at Data1 dw 2
    at Data2 dw 3
    at padding times 1000 dw 1
iend

section .text
    sub esp, MyStruct_size ; or whatever
```

Note: no 't' in the keyword  `struc` or `istruc` !

Comment: Are you saying that you *have* to do both `struc` and `istruc` before `MyStruct_size` is defined? Not just use the `struc` macro?  The manual (https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc5.html#section-5.9) says just `struc MyStruct` alone defines `MyStruct_size`, at least in current NASM 2.15.05.  So you don't need an instance of the struct in static storage just to reserve space for one on the stack.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `times 1000 dw 1` with `dw 1` 1000 times, which is exactly [what it does](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.5). Would you expect the size to be calculated properly in the expanded case?

As noted by someone else, you can just try it out:

```
MyStruct:
    .Data1 dw 2
    .Dats2 dw 3
    times 9 dw 1
MyStructEnd:
%assign    StructSize    MyStructEnd - MyStruct
    dw StructSize                        ; 00 16
%warning    The size is StructSize       ; The size is 22
```

In case you are unaware of this, you can use any hex-editor to see the output or use [assign](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.12.13) with [warning](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.9) to see the size while it assembles. It can save you the trouble of waiting for answers.

Comment: Sure it'll include the `times`. PLUS... Nasm knows `MyStruct_size` without the `equ`. We have a nice Manual...

Comment: @FrankKotler So there is. [I did not know](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.12.10). Thank you. I was going for a general approach of getting information.